# How to create a transparent window in flutter for windows?

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-layout

How can I create a transparent window in flutter for windows? My main objective is to create windows of custom shapes/rounded corners.

Simply I want to create UI like this:
https://dribbble.com/shots/15623396-Finance-Management-Personal-Dashboard-UI

How can I do that in flutter for windows?

Answer (score 0):

For the transparent part of your question I can recommend [bitsdojo_window](https://pub.dev/packages/bitsdojo_window) it has support for windows, linux and macos. Also you could just modify the windows embedding if that plugin does not fits your needs.

Now for the customs shape part  IDK of any such plugin, so you'll probably will have to modify the windows embedding(the folder that flutter creates, using c++), or create a plugin for it.
Once again if you go down that road the `bitsdojo_window` plugin is a great place to start looking at sample code that might point you to the right path of implementing it.

Comment: I have tried bitsdojo_window but it still shows shadow around window frame and regarding custom shapes if the background is transparent I can draw anything I want using flutter I don't want solution for that.

Comment: Oh ok, I missunderstood, but bear in mind that even if the window background is transparent the hit area of the window will continue to be the size of the rectangular window

Comment: Yes, that will happen but still it will give me more flexibility compared to before.